# Outlet failed error in NSWindowController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder

I have simple non document, cocoa app in which I have added new NSWindowController, named Login and I created a .xib file for it. I want this window to be opened first when the app is started.

I have changed the main interface section to my project from MainMenu to Login, and when I run the app, indeed the new login window is started first.

However...none of the outlets work. I get error message for each outlet in my login window that looks like this:

```
Failed to connect (userNameTextField) outlet from (NSApplication) to (NSTextField): missing setter or instance variable
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error message.  The solution in my case may not be directly applicable but perhaps it will help in some way.

I created a `TestWindow` view controller with associated xib and set up some referencing outlets.  I then programmatically created the window with `NSWindowController* window = [[NSWindowController alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"TestWindow"];` and got the same sort of error message. I finally realized that I should write `[TestWindow alloc]` instead of `[NSWindowController alloc]` and that fixed everything.  It seems so obvious in retrospect but I'm still getting used to what Interface Builder does and doesn't do for you auto-magically.

Your error message says it can't connect from `(NSApplication)` instead of `(YourAppClassName)`, so I suspect the class that you define your outlets in isn't actually being instantiated.